# Grails - Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:tomcat:zip:8.0.33

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Since this morning I seem to have an issue with grails plugins repo (Using Grails 2.4.4). Getting - Hostname in certificate didn't match:  != <*.jfrog.io> OR <*.jfrog.io> OR .

BuildConfig has: build 'org.grails.plugins:tomcat:8.0.33' under plugins

Anyone have encountered similar issue or have a solution for it?

```
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:tomcat:zip:8.0.33 (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:tomcat:zip:8.0.33
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:335)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:509)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.doResolve(BuildSettings.groovy:514)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.doResolve(BuildSettings.groovy)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$_getDefaultBuildDependencies_closure19.doCall(BuildSettings.groovy:775)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$_getDefaultBuildDependencies_closure19.doCall(BuildSettings.groovy)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.getDefaultBuildDependencies(BuildSettings.groovy:769)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.getBuildDependencies(BuildSettings.groovy:674)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.grails.plugins:tomcat:pom:8.0.33 from/to grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): hostname in certificate didn't match: <repo.grails.org> != <*.jfrog.io> OR <*.jfrog.io> OR <jfrog.io>
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:320)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.grails.plugins:tomcat:pom:8.0.33 from/to grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): hostname in certificate didn't match: <repo.grails.org> != <*.jfrog.io> OR <*.jfrog.io> OR <jfrog.io>
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <repo.grails.org> != <*.jfrog.io> OR <*.jfrog.io> OR <jfrog.io>
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:227)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.verify(BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.java:54)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:147)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:439)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.execute(HttpTransporter.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.implGet(HttpTransporter.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.AbstractTransporter.get(AbstractTransporter.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: I think it's not grails version related. I got the same errror with 3.1.10

Comment: repo seems to be messed up

Comment: Grails Framework ‏@grailsframework  3h3 hours ago
Central repository is back. A DNS change was done so may need time to propagate. Thanks to @jfrog for collaborating on restoring service https://twitter.com/grailsframework/status/760005383951966208

Answer (score 1):

Central repository is back. A DNS change was done so may need time to propagate. Thanks to [@jfrog](https://repo.grails.org/ui/packages) for collaborating on restoring service

> Use https://grails.jfrog.io/grails/core/ for **Grails3** and
> https://grails.jfrog.io/grails/plugins for **Grails2** until all issues
> are resolved