# Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: hostname in certificate didn't match: <repo.grails.org> != <*.jfrog.io> OR <*.jfrog.io> OR <jfrog.io>

Tags: grails

hi guys im very new to grails in fact im not even a hardcore programmer

i followed the tutorial on how to install grails on grails.org., everything is smooth from installing jdk up to setting up environment variables

i even got a successful result when i run the grails -version

but when i try to run "grails create-app test" this error pops up

Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: hostname in certificate didn't match:  != <​*.jfrog.io> OR <*​.jfrog.io> OR

i already cracked my head up in searching the net but still no luck

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38694489/grails-failed-to-read-artifact-descriptor-for-org-grails-pluginstomcatzip8

Answer (score 1):

There was a DNS issue that I think has since been resolved but may still be in the process of propagating.  See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10080.  There is a workaround described there related to using  https://grails.jfrog.io/grails/core/ for now but I think soon that won't be needed as the propagation is probably getting close to complete.

Comment: i tried adding the said repo but still the same.

here it is. 

repositories {
        mavanRepo "https://grails.jfrog.io/grails/core/"
    }